# Trigger loading on click event in tab

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a set of tabs, one of which is this one

```
<Tab eventKey="claims" id="reports-claims-tab" title="Claims">
            <Claims baseClaimId={baseClaimId} isLoading={isLoading} hasError={hasError} Claims={Claims} />
```

And have this that it's triggered right from the start

```
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [Claims, setClaims] = useState<Claim[]>([])

    useEffect(() => {
      setIsLoading(true)

      claimGateway.getClaims(baseClaimId)
        .then(res => setClaims(res.data.claims))
        .catch(() => setHasError(true))
        .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
  }, [])
```

I'm trying to make the call to just work once the tab is clicked by triggering a click event but I'm not getting this to work. I know I could just remove the call from here and move it to the child component but I was wondering if I could also do it based on this trigger event.

I tried by adding `onClick={event => handleClick(event)}` to the specific tab and `handleClick` to the hook

```
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      setIsLoading(true)

      claimCardGateway.getSimilarClaims(cockpitClaimId)
        .then(res => setSimilarClaims(res.data.similar_claims))
        .catch(() => setHasError(true))
        .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
  }, [])
  }
```

but I don't get any records this way.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is that you remove the useEffect completely and call the api on the click of the button

```
const handleClick=() => {
   setLoading(true);
   // call API here directly

}
```

But since the state of the loading state is used, you can make the API call by changing the state of the component which would then trigger your useEffect since loading is added in dependency array of useEffect. This would ensure that the API is called only after the loading is set is true

```
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
 if(loading) {
    // call your API here
}
 
},[loading])


const handleClick=(e) => {
    setLoading(true);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your insights, that helped. It didn't fully work as is on my setup, because it seems that Tab component onClick event is controlled by the parent controller. So I had to change it to `const handleClick = eventKey => {
    if (eventKey === 'claims') {
      setIsLoading(true)
    }
  }}` and add `onSelect={handleClick}` to the parent `Tabs`. Baring in mind that I already had `<Tab eventKey="claims"`